# How to remove part of characters in data frame column

Tags: r, function, remove-if

I have a data frame as follows (part of a larger set):

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXmwy.jpg)

for the column `raw$Zipcode` I need to remove the two `00` before the Zipcode number for Swedish zipcodes (preferably through a function). I am very new to R and have found `gsub` and `strsplit` but can't seem to make it work:

```
raw2 <- unlist(strsplit(raw$ZipCode, split="00", fixed=TRUE))[2]
```

The zeroes are characters as other countries in the data set have letters. How can I remove the first two zeroes in all cases of the two first character letters being zeroes in a column?

Comment: Please do not show data using images. Consider using `dput(df)`  to get the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. Using `as.numeric` on a column of your choice.

```
raw$Zipcode <- as.numeric(raw$Zipcode)
```

2. If you want it to be a `character` then you can use `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
raw$Zipcode <- str_replace(raw$Zipcode, "^0+" ,"")
```

3. There is another function called `str_remove` in `stringr` package.

```
raw$Zipcode <- str_remove(raw$Zipcode, "^0+")
```

4. You can also use `sub` from base R.

```
raw$Zipcode <- sub("^0+", "", raw$Zipcode)
```

But if you want to remove `n` number of leading zeroes, replace `+` with `{n}` to remove them.

For instance to remove two 0's use `sub("^0{2}", "", raw$Zipcode)`.

Comment: Thanks alot! So the ansswer is to substitute the 0 with a nothing "" in the function: sub("^0{2}", "", raw$Zipcode). Also if you will be so kind, what is the meaning of the "^"

Comment: Yes! If that has solved your problem, please consider accepting as an answer by clicking the grey tick on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c("00345", "00045", "12345", "12005")

sub("^0{2}", "", v)

# [1] "345"   "045"   "12345" "12005"
```